# ASP.NET Core how to use [asp-page] Tag Helper without query string?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I know that `asp-route-{key}` is to add parameters to `asp-action`, `asp-page`, etc.

But if I use `asp-page` in a page that already contains query strings like :

```
http://localhost/page?query=some-query-parameter&param=another-query-parameter
```

And when i use anchor tag helper like :

```
<a asp-page="anotherpage">Go to another page</a>
```

The generated anchor tag will be pointing to :

```
http://localhost/anotherpage?query=some-query-parameter&param=another-query-parameter
```

But what I want is simply :

```
http://localhost/anotherpage
```

I found that I can use `<a href="@Url.Page("/Path/To/Page")">` but I think it's not a good way to go.